# How do I derive camera pose from a known point cloud?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Given a robust sparse point cloud, and a set of views (cameras) of this point cloud, how do I determine the world position and orientation of the cameras using OpenCV?

Note that I have the intrinsic parameters of each camera (they are identical), and the point cloud points are defined as 3d world coordinates.

Comment: what do you mean by a point cloud to be a 4x4 matrix? shouldn't a point cloud be a set of 3D (or extended 3D) points?
Do you have corresponding points in 2D camera images with known 3D points?

Comment: You're right. My wires were crossed with camera extrinsic matrices. I have updated the body.

Comment: do you have 2D point correspondences (matchings) of your 3D points between your `set of views` and the camera from which you want to extract the pose?

Comment: I have both. I have tried using solvePnPRansac, but get results that fluctuate wildly in world position.

Comment: did you consider lens distortion? can you post sample images (from both, your set of views and from the query images)

Comment: I'm using the [MPI-Sintel](http://sintel.is.tue.mpg.de/) dataset, which contains no lens distortion (it is synthesized from Blender). My distortion coefficients are set to 0.

Comment: It seems somebody else has the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898698/pose-estimation-solvepnp-and-epipolar-geometry-do-not-agree